# stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString doesn't accept multiple words

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

So I have the following line of code:

```
text = [text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%@" withString:[NSString stringWithString:name]];
```

The `[NSString stringWithString:name]` protects against single character string exceptions.

However, now my issue is that if someone enters a `name` that is more than one word, i.e. `name = @"John Doe";`, the entire line fails.  I feel this is a very simple fix, but for the life of me cannot figure it out.  Anyone know what's up?

**EDIT: Including code around line of error.**

This function stores the name:

```
- (void) buttonSelected:(UIButton *)button
{
NSString *text;
if ([button.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"NEXT"]  || [button.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"DEBATE BACK"] || [button.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"ISSUE A CLOTURE"])
{
    bool noText = true;
    bool foundTextBox = false;
    for (UIView *view in [scrollView subviews])
    {
        if (view.tag == 51)
        {
            if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
            {
                foundTextBox = true;
                UITextField *blah = (UITextField *)view;
                text = blah.text;
                NSLog(@"%@", text);
                if (![text isEqualToString:@""] && text != nil) noText = false;
            }
        }
    }
    if (!foundTextBox) noText = false;
    if (!noText)
    {
        if (questionNumber == 0)        name = text;
        else if (questionNumber == 1)   state = text;
        else if (questionNumber == 2)   billSubject = text;
        [self hideKeyboard];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.8 animations:^
         {
             for (UIView *view in [scrollView subviews])
             {
                 CGPoint origin = CGPointMake(-10 - (view.frame.size.width/2), view.frame.origin.y+(view.frame.size.height/2));
                 [view setTag:view.tag + 100];
                 [view setCenter:origin];
                 [view setAlpha:0.0];
             }
         }
         completion:^(BOOL finished)
         {
             for (UIView *view in [scrollView subviews])
             {
                 [view removeFromSuperview];
             }
             [self nextQuestion];
         }];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning!" message:@"You have not entered any text!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show]; [alert release];
    }
}
}
```

Now that I think about it, the `NSLog(@"%@", text);` never actually prints for some reason.  Not even a blank line. However, `noText` is still false after the for loop that looks for a text box;

Here is the calling of `name`:

```
- (void) setText:(NSString *) text label:(UILabel *) label
{
if (questionNumber == 1)
{
    NSLog(@"%@", name);
    text = [text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%@" withString:[NSString stringWithString:name]];
    label.text = text;
}
else
    label.text = text;
}
```

`name` does print the entire name.

Note: `questionNumber`, `name`, `state`, and `billSubject` are all global variables.

Comment: Why are you trying to replace %@ ? I think you might be confused with stringWithFormat

Comment: have you have tried not to use `stringWithString`? Just `text = [text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%@" withString:name];`

Comment: And you really want to replace %@ for the name variable value?

Comment: "The [NSString stringWithString:name] protects against single character string exceptions." ???????  Where did you get this?

Comment: Hot Licks, if I don't change the format over, it throws an exception when the string is only one character long.  Don't know why, but the `[NSString stringWithString:name]` solves the issue

Comment: CainaSouza: yes.  The string goes like this: Blah Blah %@ blah blah where the "%@" should be replaced with the name.

Comment: @Jack Freeman: I am pulling the string from a plist.  Will using `stringWithFormat` work here?

Comment: @JackFreeman: I just tried to use the `stringWithFormat` and it just quits the entire app.

Comment: I don't know what your trying to do. If you have a string in your plist with the following "Blah Blah %@ blah blah" then you could do text = [NSString stringWithFormat:text, name];

Comment: There is something flaky about "name".  How are you getting it?

Comment: (stringWithString doesn't "change the format".  Generally it does absolutely nothing.  There's something flaky about "name".)

Comment: Hint:  Do `NSLog(@"Name is %@", name);`  See what you get when you have a multi-word name.

Comment: Here's the output: `2013-03-14 17:38:51.270 XXX[37013:c07] John Doe`

Comment: After stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString is called, what is the value of text?  You should NSLog that too.

Comment: And remove that stupid stringWithString call!!!

Comment: You don't have a property named "text", do you???

Comment: The situation you're describing here doesn't sound like the program is otherwise working correctly. Your app shouldn't crash when a string is one character or two words. There has to be some root problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to solve this issue, although it wasn't a perfect solution.  I combined `name`, `state`, and `billSubject` into one `NSMutableArray` that would store them.  It now recalls all cases of a word, whether its one character or 10 words in one string.  Don't know what was wrong with global `NSString`'s but this issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

`[text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"some character pattern" withString:name]`

(What is the "some character pattern" you wish to replace?  Is it really "%@"??  Or maybe just "@", or something else?)

Comment: it's really "%@".  The string is "Welcome, Representative %@.  What state do you represent?" and I am trying to replace the %@ with their name.

Comment: Just use `[text StringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%@" withString:name]`.  If it's not handling "multiple words" it's because the "multiple words" never actually got into "name", probably due to the way you're parsing them from whatever input you have.

Comment: The output gives me the full name I've typed in, so it must be the way it's parsing

Comment: @tokan_one - Then that full name would be substituted into the string.  You should post your code (the main part of it), since clearly there is something you're mucking up.  Eg, your claim that stringWithString somehow prevents a single character from causing problems is almost certainly bogus.

Comment: I have added in the blocks of code for you in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool noText = true;
bool foundTextBox = false;
for (UIView *view in [scrollView subviews])
{
    if (view.tag == 51)
    {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
        {
            foundTextBox = true;
            UITextField *blah = (UITextField *)view;
            text = blah.text;
            NSLog(@"%@", text);
            if (![text isEqualToString:@""] && text != nil) noText = false;
        }
    }
}
if (!foundTextBox) noText = false;
```

if foundTextBox gets set to true, !foundTextBox will be false, and and noText will remain true.  noText is only set false if foundTextBox is false.

(This is unnecessarily confusing logic.)